# Photo Failed to manipulate with MiniMagick, maybe it is not an image? error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, minimagick

I have the following code, which resizes and image and then adds some hex background. On localhost this works, but on heroku i get the following error

```
version :big do
  process :offer_resize_and_pad
 end

def offer_resize_and_pad
  img = resize_and_pad(600, nil, model.hex, 'Center')
  img
end
```

`"Photo Failed to manipulate with MiniMagick, maybe it is not an image? Original Error: Command (\"mogrify -thumbnail \"600x>\" -background \"#fff\" -gravity \"Center\" -extent \"600x\" /tmp/mini_magick20130217-2-1hts61y.jpg\") failed: {:status_code=>1, :output=>\"mogrify: Empty JPEG image (DNL not supported)`/tmp/mini_magick20130217-2-1hts61y.jpg' @ jpeg.c/EmitMessage/232.\n\"

Comment: This could be because you don't have the same access to the file system on Heroku as you do on your local machine i.e. the /tmp directory.

Comment: You have a point. But then, how can I fix this? . And there are other pictures from other uploaders, that work.

Comment: A similar error started when I updated my Gemfile from mini_magick (4.0.1) to (4.3.6), see https://github.com/minimagick/minimagick/issues/338

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I 've used RMagick instead of Mini_magick, with some syntax changes , and it seems to work :) .

```
include CarrierWave::RMagick

def offer_resize_and_pad
  img = resize_and_pad(600, 280, model.hex, ::Magick::CenterGravity)
  img
end
```

Comment: please extend your answer. in order for the answer to be helpful for future visitors, you should post the solution which worked for you in the end.